# Setting and getting "data" from PyQt widget items?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

This is not so much a question as it is a request for an explanation. I'm following Mark Summerfield's "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt", and I must've missed something because I cannot make sense of the following mechanism to link together a real "instance_item" which I am using and is full of various types of data, and a "widget_item" which represents it in a QTreeWidget model for convenience.

Setting:

```
widget_item.setData(0, Qt.UserRole, QVariant(long(id(instance_item))))
```

Getting

```
widget_item.data(0, Qt.UserRole).toLongLong()[0]
```

Stuff like `toLongLong()` doesn't seem "Pythonic" at all, and why are we invoking Qt.UserRole and QVariant? are the "setData" and "data" functions part of the Qt framework or is it a more general Python command?

Comment: Oh yeah, the "0" refers to the column in the tree, and is not necessary when using lists. I do understand that part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least 2 better solutions. In order of increasing pythonicity:

1) You don't need *quite* so much data type packing

```
widget_item.setData(0, Qt.UserRole, QVariant(instance_item))
widget_item.data(0, Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
```

2) There is an alternate API to PyQt4 where QVariant is done away with, and the conversion to-from QVariant happens transparently. To enable it, you need to add the following lines *before* any PyQt4 import statements:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
```

Then, your code looks like this:

```
widget_item.setData(0, Qt.UserRole, instance_item)
widget_item.data(0, Qt.UserRole)  # original python object
```

Note that there is also an option `sip.setapi('QString', 2)` where QString is done away with, and you can use unicode instead.

Answer (score 5):

All of these methods -- setData(), data(), toLongLong() are all part of Qt and were originally intended to be used in C++, where they make a lot more sense. I'm not really sure what the author is trying to do here, but if you find yourself doing something terribly un-pythonic, there is probably a better way:

```
## The setter:
widget_item.instance_item = instance_item

## The getter:
instance_item = widget_item.instance_item
```

The Qt docs can't recommend this, of course, because there are no dynamic attribute assignments in C++. There are a few very specific instances when you may have to deal with QVariant and other such nonsense (for example, when dealing with databases via QtSQL), but they are quite rare.

Comment: Does this persist over drag/drop to a new QListWidget?